# "I wish I could say…"

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, word-order

Just wondering how you would say "I wish I could say "I miss you""? 
I was thinking it would be something along the lines of 「恋しい」語るできたらいいのに although I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: How Japanese do you know? I'm asking because 語る looks like too straight a translation for "to tell", even though the are much easier (and more common) verbs for this.

Comment: @Earthliŋ do you mean how much Japanese because I don't know that much. I know there's a lot of different ways to say or to tell so I wasn't sure which you would use or how.

Comment: Can you elaborate slightly on the situation in which you'd use the English sentence? I can think of various interpretations and I don't think you'd express them the same way in Japanese.

Comment: @snailboat I was thinking of saying "I miss you (会いたい) but I wish I could say I miss you (恋しい)". Since one means you have to be able to see the person in the future apparently. I run an Instagram profile which I upload photos with small Japanese phrases or words as an aesthetic I suppose you could say.

Comment: Like those facebook sentimental messages that people bombard you with? I've never heard 恋しい used in conversation before... it's an い adjective, isn't it? I'm not sure that it actually means "I miss you" in the way that "miss" is used in English... for that matter, 会いたい, wanting to meet/see you is basically as close as they get to the idea of "missing" someone as far as I know, and that doesn't really capture the sense of "missing" someone either... that sense that some piece is missing from our lives, it's not a sentiment that can be reduced to a single japanese word...

Comment: @Kazuki, I don't think either phrase implies that you will definitely be able to meet the person you miss, in the future...  会いたい人　would be "person I want/long to see" while  恋しい人 would be something like "person my heart is drawn to" as far as I can tell...

Comment: As for the 'I wish I could say [...]' part I guess you could translate it by '[...] to ietara ii (no ni)'